# Identity and inheritance Error On Migration: A key cannot be configured on 'Person' because it is a derived type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and Identity.
I have created a simple app:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}


public class User : IdentityUser
{
}

public class Person : User
{
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Person>
{
    public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Document> Document { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=EFCoreDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
}
```

When I want to add a migration It gave me this error:

> A key cannot be configured on 'Person' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'User'. If you did not intend for 'User' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not included in a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation property on a type that is included in the model.

I have tested these changes:

1) If Owner became of type Person the error goes, but this is not an option for me because in fact User and Document are in a library and my final app use that library and Person is in the App.

2) If ApplicationDbContext inherits from DbContext the error goes.

Is there any workaround available?

Comment: Why do you even have a `DbSet<Person>` when inheriting from `IdentityDbContext<Person>` will give you this anyway?

Comment: @DavidG I have removed that, but no effect.

Comment: Maybe you can try to link Person to a user with a foreign key, and make this foreign key a part of the primary key of Person

Comment: Since your root entity is `User` (because of the need of `public User Owner { get; set; }`), your context should derive from `IdentityDbContext<User>`

Comment: The best solution is to not mix contexts. Just add a person table to the `business context` which has a foreign key field that links to the current user (e.g. based on `sub` claim), without being a 'real' database relation.

Comment: @IvanStoev that was a good Idea

Answer (score 2):

For using `Person` and `IdentityDbContext` without changing `Document`, you could implement a new model from `Document`, and change it to `Person`.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContextTest : IdentityDbContext<Person>
{
    public DbSet<MyDocument> Document { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFCoreDemo;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    }
}
public class User : IdentityUser
{
}

public class Person : User
{
}
public class MyDocument:Document
{
    public new Person Owner { get; set; }
}
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution it seems it cheats EF and the nice thing is when I call .Include(d => d.Owner) it will load a person and set value of MyDocument.Owner.

Comment: @HamedH if it works, would you minding accepting it as answer?

Comment: This can be used as a solution for simple cases but the downside is the need for new classes for each model that for more complex situation is not suitable. I currently use your solution but wondering if it can be done without class MyDocument

Comment: The exception is thrown anytime when deriving from base entity, but somewhere in the being build EE model the base type is referenced.